# How to resolve Azure "Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server"?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I get the following error message, when I try to connect to SQL Azure.

> Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server

I'm using an Azure connection string. On development I'm running against SQL Server Express. This specific error is thrown when I try to fetch some data from the database.

The context that I'm using is running in a using clause, see below

```
function List<SomeType> GetList(string dbContextName) 
{ 
    using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext) 
    {
         return context.SomeTypes.ToList();
    } 
}
```

We're using Entity Framework version 4.2, ASP.NET MVC 3 and .NET 4.0.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It seems pretty clear that you need to use a SQL login instead of a Windows login for security - i.e. no SSPI etc; just a SQL username/password

Comment: **SHOW US** the connection string(s) used ! You **cannot** use the `Integrated Security=SSPI;` setting against SQL Azure, that probably is the default for your local SQL Server Express installation...

Comment: How on earth do you manually enter a connection string to SSMS? It doesn't have anywhere to paste one.

Answer (score 55):

I was using user/pass and still got the error message.  But, I added this to my connection string and it worked.

```
Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
```

Answer (score 21):

Set

```
Integrated Security=False
```

In Connection String.

Comment: I just deleted "`Integrated Security=True`" entirely and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

You've probably used the incorrect connection string, this is the connection string format that worked for my case:

"ConnectionString": "Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"

Answer (score 7):

Integrated authentication (i.e. SSPI in the connection string) is NOT supported in SQL Azure.
Only SQL Authentication is supported (i.e. username & password in the connection string)

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned by others, only SQL Server authentication is supported in SQL Azure.
You can read more on [Guidelines and Limitations with SQL Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features). As well as the [Security Guidelines and limitations for SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394108.aspx).

You have to [CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336268.aspx) by yourself in your MASTER database, then you will want to [CREATE USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336277.aspx) in your custom Azure Database. Also do not forget to execute sys.sp_addrolemember to grant some permissions to your user.

More on [managing users and logins in SQL Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins) can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins).

And, at the end, you can always look at the invaluable source for [connection strings](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-azure).

Comment: it has been changed and Azure SQL supports [Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication)

Answer (score 5):

```
1.**Windows Authentication** is not supported in Azure so you should go with **SQL Server Authentication**.
2.When you use SQL server Authentication you should pass User Id(Login in SQL server) and Password(Password in SQL server).
3.User Id should contain space in between should not be like UserId.
4.Trusted_Connection should be false.
The connection string in *appsettings.json* look like this:

"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBContext": "Server=ServerName;Database=DbName;User Id=loginName;Password=loginPassword;Trusted_Connection=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding this question because you're using **SSMS** and getting this error **even though are 100% not selecting Windows Authentication** then I can assure you that you're not losing your mind.

On a new Windows + SSMS install I just tried connecting via:

```
File > Connect Object Explorer
```

I got the error message about Windows Authentication not being supported (I'm not even using a domain). After trying three times (with SQL Server Authentication selected), I switched to logging in using

```
Object Explorer > Connect > Database Engine
```

and it worked first time.