# Protecting SQL Server connection String

Tags: windows, password-protection

We have servers (Windows 2012) in the field, not under company control. They connect to SQL Server. We want to secure the connection string. We can encrypt it but at some point the applications (.NET 2015) will decrypt it and make the connection. We are looking at obfuscating the executables to prevent debugging, or at least prevent debugging until we become aware the local machines are compromised at which point we would delete that connection. Is there best practices for doing this? I believe we cannot use Windows Authentication with SQL Server on Azure:

[How to resolve Azure “Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818354/how-to-resolve-azure-windows-logins-are-not-supported-in-this-version-of-sql-se)

Am I understanding that correctly?

The safest path seems to be obfuscation. The servers do not run Ultimate so we cannot use Bit Locker.