# How to bcp into an existing text file in my Azure Virtual Directory and save as text(tab delimited)

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure account hosting my asp.net mvc 5 application. I created a virtual directory called **virtlocation** for the website. The virtual directory is in the KUDU Console and contains a text file called **newitemsfeed.txt** . So it can be accessed as **abc.com/virtlocation/newitemsfeed.txt**

How do I write data to that text file in that location from data in my Azure SQL database. Specifically how do I write the correct code to get my data saved to the location in the specific format of a **.txt** as **Text(tab delimited)**.

My guess is that I need to write the code inside the SCM area of the application. I see we have the option to use CMD or PowerShell from the Debug Console in Azure.

Below is a great starting point example I was given but do not quite understand how to translate that to write to a file that exists in my virtual directory.

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.products" queryout <filepath>test.txt -S <servername>.database.windows.net -d <databasename> -U <username> -P <password>
```

So if I try and replicate that using my credentials for example I have come up with this:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.products" queryout /virtlocation/newitemsfeed.txt -S abcexampleserver.database.windows.net -d xyzcorpdbase -U mrxloginn -P password123
```

The problems with how I have written that are the following:

1. How does that snippet let the situation know that its to be saved in the format of  .txt file as **Text(tab delimited)** and NOT a regular text file? (It's for a feed that I need to have it formatted it with tabbed spaces on the header and not in plain text as you get when you see database results)
2. I still do not know what to add to the snippet so it allows access to write to the virtual directory... the credentials I am providing are for the server name and database, but nothing there indicates the access to the app server so it can actually get in the virtual directory.

I know I am missing a few things in the snippet but not sure what and how to write the correct statement. All help is appreciated!

Comment: bcp is a command line program which can extract data from sql server and write it to files. You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16 it will also list various parameters you can use to control the output

Comment: if you run this command on the azure server, what does it output

Comment: When I run that command I get "Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server." I have searched for that error and read that you should be using SQL login for the database. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818354/how-to-resolve-azure-windows-logins-are-not-supported-in-this-version-of-sql-se ) That database that I am trying to use in the snippet is infact using SQL Login and my connection string meets the suggested parameters in the link I posted in this comment.

Comment: -U: Specifies the login ID used to connect to SQL Azure server. You must append the SQL Azure server name to the login name in the connection string by using the <login>@<servername> notation. Did you do this?

Comment: Ok looks like I got it to work (it did not save my data as tab delimited but it was able to authenticate to the database connection) Now just have to figure out how to save with tab delimited instead of a plain text file. I wrote the code as you suggested just now in the format of <login>@<servername> Like this: 


bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.products" queryout /virtlocation/newitemsfeed.txt -S abcexampleserver.database.windows.net -d xyzcorpdbase -U mrxloginn@abcexampleserver -P password123 -w -r \r -t,

Comment: Ok problems solved! Instead of me writing the query straight in the command prompt I had to call a stored procedure since it was a very lengthy SQL query. In that SP, I had written the proper code needed to save the file as tab delimited.